# High chart data downloads but does not display in browser using node

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm having an issue with High Charts I don't understand. I'm able to download the chart from the browser but it does not display.

Here is my javascript file.

`chart.js`

```
var cpvmPartners = [];
var cpvmPlannedCPM = [];
graphData = []


$(function(){
    $.getJSON('/cpvmdata', function(data) {
        for(k in data){
             graphData.push([data[k]['partner'],data[k]['plannedcpm']])
        }
});


    $(function () {
        $('#cpvmSummary').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Population',
                data: graphData ,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                    y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

This is the html

```
 <div class="container">

        <!-- Portfolio Item Heading -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">CPVM Summary
           <!--          <small>CPVM Summary</small> -->
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
   <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/cpvmGraphs.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!-- High Charts -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Not sure what else to do at this point pr why it is loading in one place but not the other, any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any sort of errors in the console?

Comment: its because you are getting the data in one 'one dom ready' function, and then rendering the chart in another. Your data get is asynchronous, so its not there until it comes back, but you render the chart before that.

Comment: to fix this, put all your chart stuff in a separate function, lets say we call it renderChart, then AFTER you get the json, in the other function, you render your chart in there, passing the data in... does that make sense?

Comment: @Omarjmh Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: see below.. for a written out answer with link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are getting the data in one 'on DOM ready' function, and then rendering the chart in another. Your data get is asynchronous, so its not there until it comes back, but you render the chart before that.

To fix this, put all your chart stuff in a separate function, lets say we call it renderChart, then AFTER you get the JSON, in the other function, render your chart  passing the data in.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3